# Saving PPM in Fortran

Tags: fortran

So, as an exercise to learn Fortran, I decided to reimplement an assignment from my parallel programming class whose aim is to load, horizontally blur, and then save a PPM (P3) image file.  My [code](https://pastebin.com/2eubyFjV) works for reading (it has proper depth and dimensions), but when I go to save the data, the image comes out garbled and with almost half of the data missing.

```
subroutine loadppm( this, filename )
        class( ppmfile )                   :: this
        character( len = * ), intent( in ) :: filename

        integer              :: funit, cdepth, cwidth, cheight, x, y, cr, cg, cb, reason
        character( 2 )       :: header

        open( newunit = funit, file = filename, status = 'old', action = 'read', access = 'stream', form = 'formatted' )

        read( funit, '(a2)' ) header
        if ( header /= 'P3' ) then
            print *, "Invalid file type detected."
            stop
        end if

        read( funit, * ) cwidth, cheight
        read( funit, * ) cdepth

        if ( cdepth /= 255 ) then
            print *, "Invalid colour depth detected."
            stop
        end if

        this%width  = cwidth
        this%height = cheight
        this%depth  = cdepth

        allocate( this%data( 3, this%width, this%height ) )

        do y = 1, this%width
            do x = 1, this%height
                read( funit, *, IOSTAT = reason ) cr, cg, cb

                if ( reason < 0 ) then
                    ! EOF reached
                    exit
                    exit
                end if

                this%data( 1, y, x ) = cr
                this%data( 2, y, x ) = cg
                this%data( 3, y, x ) = cb
            end do
        end do

        close( funit )
    end subroutine loadppm
```

I've narrowed it down to the loadppm() method.  For some reason, it reads the first pixel correctly.  For some reason, every other pixel read in is wrong.  The format I'm trying to read boils down to:

```
P3
2 2
255
232 112 255 255 255 255
112 212 2 97 12 112
```

The first line is the header, the second is the dimensions, the third is the colour depth (always 255).  All lines afterwards are pixel data, each triple are the RGB values of a given pixel.  When I have it output what's read in, the first triple is correct (as in, it matches what's in the file), but everything afterward is wrong; as in, it doesn't match what's in the file.  Newlines are ignored in the file, but there's only ever a single space between any given value.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Please put the code here as text, do not just link it. It is very important.  If it is too large, make a smaller [mcve].

Comment: Amended with the offending method, with debugging info removed.

Comment: *every other pixel read in is wrong*  In what way(s) wrong ?  Imagine you are a patient visiting a doctor and you tell the doctor *My leg isn't working*, then the doctor is going to start asking a series of questions to figure out what is wrong with your leg.  Now imagine you are someone trying to help a noob on SO and try to anticipate all the questions we might need answered ...

Answer (score 1):

Erik,

The problem you're having is your use of the read statement. In fortran, a read statement will always advance to the next line after it is completed, even if there is data remaining on the line. This is why some of your data was read correctly, it was the data at the start of the line.

If all of the integers in your PPM were exactly 3 characters, you could solve this using `advance='no'`:

```
READ( funit, '(I3)', IOSTAT = reason, advance='no' ) cr
READ( funit, '(I3)', IOSTAT = reason, advance='no' ) cg
READ( funit, '(I3)', IOSTAT = reason, advance='no' ) cb
```

But for your more general case, you'll want to read the entire line in as a string, and manually split it in to your array.